# 1 click auto login for user accounts

Tags: users, login

Looking to setup a public facing, launchpad page that lists out all of the user accounts with a 1 click login.

I realize the security implications of such a page but we need something like this to rapidly test multiple accounts different sections of the site.

What's the best way to create something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're already aware of the security implications. :)

Write a [simple plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that exposes a controller action where you pass in the user's ID to it.

All that action does is call:

```
craft()->userSession->loginUserById($userId);
```